# Only root can send notification

Tags: gnome, services, notification, segmentation-fault

I'm aware of the two other posts describing the same problem, however none of the solutions proposed there have worked for me.

I'm running `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS` and using `GNOME 42.9` as my Desktop environment.

**Description of the issue**

My main issue is that using `notify-send` as a regular user results in the following error message:

```
robin@robin-workstation:~$ notify-send "test"
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications received signal 11
```

There seem to be no process running related to notification, which is the reason why the error message mentions "StartServiceByName", it's probably trying to start the service since this is the first time it's needed. However starting the service seems to fail with a segfault (signal 11 = segfault, if I'm googling right).

When trying to start the `notification-daemon` myself I indeed get a Segmentation Fault:

```
robin@robin-workstation:~$ /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
Segmentation fault
```

When trying to run the same program as root using `sudo`, it simply hangs in my terminal. Interestingly, when I look at running programs while it hangs, I do see it in the list of running programs, but attempting to notify-send still fails with the same error message...

```
robin@robin-workstation:~$ ps aux | grep notification
robin       2262  0.0  0.0 250308 11892 ?        Ssl  14:42   0:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-print-notifications
root        7254  0.2  0.0  14268  5700 pts/0    S+   15:27   0:00 sudo /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
root        7255  2.4  0.1 263632 22144 pts/0    Sl+  15:27   0:00 /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
robin       7268  0.0  0.0   9216  2276 pts/2    S+   15:27   0:00 grep --color=auto notification
robin@robin-workstation:~$ notify-send "test"
Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Process org.freedesktop.Notifications received signal 11
```

**Additional info**

I'm not using `notify-osd` (it is not installed on my machine). `libnotify-bin` and `notification-daemon` are installed and at the latest version:

```
robin@robin-workstation:~$ sudo apt install notification-daemon
notification-daemon is already the newest version (3.20.0-4build1).

robin@robin-workstation:~$ sudo apt install libnotify-bin
libnotify-bin is already the newest version (0.7.9-3ubuntu5.22.04.1).
```

The content of the notifications `.service` file seem legit (which makes sense, the problem doesn't seem that the system can't find the service, but that it can't start it because it segfault):

```
robin@robin-workstation:~$ cat /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

I've tried reinstalling `notification-daemon` and `libnotify-bin`, without effect.

Any ideas worth investigating would be appreciated!
Thanks!

As requested here's my `env`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/robin-workstation:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2119,unix/robin-workstation:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2119
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
PWD=/home/robin
LOGNAME=robin
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=2308
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.3SZDE2
HOME=/home/robin
USERNAME=robin
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00[...]
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
VTE_VERSION=6800
WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/5df7e24d_8b5c_40c5_a6a3_3c74bdc3c336
GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=:1
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=robin
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.104
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=a4
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PATH=/home/robin/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/robin
```

Comment: The big question is where does this `root        7254  0.2  0.0  14268  5700 pts/0    S+   15:27   0:00 sudo /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon` spring from? Can you make a testuser so we know if it is in your $HOME ore systemwide problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my description was probably not clear: this process is listed here because I start it in another terminal windows, using sudo. It simply hangs there until I Ctrl+C it and while it hangs, I get this process listed in the ps output in my other terminal windows.

I created another user to try to reproduce the behavior: I've got a different error but I still can't use notify-send:
`Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=78171097eee3423d94a70b306f1f17ec --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1`

Comment: you do not try this on a remote system; like over ssh? If not can you add `env`please.

Comment: Nope, this is on the machine itself, not via ssh.
My `env` is super cluttered, I don't really know why it's like this. I'm adding it to the original post.

Comment: same behaviour if you start a X11 session instead wayland?  I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Good call! I never use X11 (to be honest I'm a Ubuntu noob and I'm not really sure I could explain the difference between X11 and wayland to a 5 year old) but if I start a session in X11 instead of Wayland then it works! Any idea of what I could look at to investigate this further? In the meantime I'll go read up on session management, X11 and Wayland...

Comment: I would say in wayland session some Environment variable are not Set correct. But I use lubuntu so X11 Session.